# Why am I unable to position my view with a gradient sublayer with Auto Layout? It doesn't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I have the following code to create a view with a gradient background (using a sub layer) and then add it as a subview:

```
// Add a gradient overlay to make caption more legible (add a little extra to the sides to make it continue over the spacing between view controllers)
UIView *gradientView = [[UIView alloc] init];
gradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
gradientView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

// Add the gradient effect
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = gradientView.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor,
                    (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.65].CGColor,
                    (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor];
gradient.locations = @[@0.0, @0.77, @1.0];

[gradientView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

[self.view addSubview:gradientView];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:gradientView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:gradientView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:gradientView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:gradientView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

However, when I run it, nothing shows up. If I set it up with a frame instead of Auto Layout, it does work. Why am I unable to do this with Auto Layout?

Answer (score 1):

`CALayer`s don't follow Auto Layout, only UIKit views. Your gradient layer is begin added, but it probably just has a zero size frame. Best bet is subclass `UIView` and use `+[UIView layerClass]` to return a `CAGradientLayer`, then it will automatically match the size of the view under Auto Layout, otherwise you'll need to position your layers manually using something like `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the height and width constraints, pass `nil` for the `toItem:` parameter and 0 for the 2nd attribute. I noticed that you set the constants to 0, which means your gradient view will have no size.

Also, the height and width constraints should be added to the `gradientView`, not the main view.

Comment: I thought you always add constraints to the view it's a part of?

Comment: The rule is not so straight forward: the rule is something like… install constraints on the nearest ancestor of the views involved and the nearest ancestor for width and height constraints is the view itself. I'm paraphrasing the rule badly from memory.

Comment: Okay, why do I have to pass nil, though? It's in reference to self.view.